# Ion Auth , Get all current logged in users logged

Tags: codeigniter-2, ion-auth

I'm using ion auth library with codeigniter.
I can get all members on ceratin group but can't get all logged_in users in that group. 
Does anyone know how can i achieve this?
Thank you all

Ok im edditing this because i found a way of doing it...
I ve passed my session for database , table ci_sessions, and now i can see the users logged on based on table number of rows.

i found another problem.

I'm unserializing user_data of ci_sessions this way

```
       $query = $this->db->get('ci_sessions');

       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
          var_dump([$row->user_data]);
          $user_data = unserialize($row->user_data);
          var_dump($user_data);
       }
```

and i get user_data as an array like this

```
    array (size=6)
      'user_data' => string '' (length=0)
      'identity' => string 'joao.costa@onegreat.org' (length=23)
      'username' => string 'joao.costa' (length=10)
      'email' => string 'joao.costa@onegreat.org' (length=23)
      'user_id' => string '14' (length=2)
      'old_last_login' => string '1347619173' (length=10)
```

i can't now get my user_id cause it says user_id is a string nd the 14 too.

what am i doing wrong?

i tried doing something like this

```
    user_data->user_id
```

thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you unserialising the array? There is no need.

```
       $query = $this->db->get('ci_sessions');

       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
          var_dump([$row->user_data]);
          $user_data = $row->user_data;
          var_dump($user_data);
          // or
          var_dump($user_data->user_id);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the elements in the array, use array notation:

> user_data['user_id']